# Spinnaker on Vagrant - Modifying Gate URL for Deck UI

Tags: vagrant, spinnaker

I have installed Spinnaker on a Vagrant Machine running Ubuntu 14.04

All my components are running successfully (Checked Active Ports , all logs)

I am also binding Deck UI and Gate on all network interfaces by specifying custom settings

When i access Deck UI from the host machine on VagrantIP at 9000, the UI comes up successfully. But Deck UI tries to access gate on localhost at 8084 and gets a "Connection Refused". 
My Gate is running at  "http://VagrantIP:8084"

Where do i modify the URL with which Deck accesses Gate?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind spinnaker to the `0.0.0.0` network interface so it will be available when accessed from your local machine.

You can read the following blog post https://blog.spinnaker.io/exposing-spinnaker-to-end-users-4808bc936698 but basically the following should do the trick

> We’ll specify the `0.0.0.0` host in both `gate.yml` and `deck.yml` in our
>   default Halyard deployment with this command:
>
> ```
> echo "host: 0.0.0.0" | tee \
>      ~/.hal/default/service-settings/gate.yml \
>      ~/.hal/default/service-settings/deck.yml 
> sudo hal deploy apply
> ```

Comment: I have done that. After having that done that, i did confirm that gate and deck are now listening on all network interfaces. The problem is slightly different. In the Deck UI, a javascript file called vendor_bundle.js is trying to access Gate at localhost 8084. That will never work because "localhost" is my host machine and everything is running inside a Vagrant Machine. How Can i tell Deck UI to access Gate over a specific URL. Really appreciate your inputs.

Comment: I can access spinnaker from my local machine, it's that the javascript of the UI cannot access Gate over localhost . I hope that clarifies my issue.

Comment: Look at the linked post. you need to `hal config security ui edit \
    --override-base-url http://spinnaker.mydomain.org:9000
&&
hal config security api edit \
    --override-base-url http://spinnaker.mydomain.org:8084
&&
hal deploy apply`